# Ruby access 'key' of Object?

Tags: ruby, hash, key

If I have a class, is there a way to catch the key access event?

```
obj = Example.new
obj['key'] # is there any way to manually handle this?
```

When I use `method_missing`, I only get `'[]'` as the name, but I do not get the `'key'` keyword. I have also tried to inherit `Hash` with `Example < Hash` but `obj['key']` would simply resolve to `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple, actually:

```
class Example
  def [](key)
    p key
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    p [ key, value ]
  end
end
```

You can do the same with `method_missing` but if you're intending to capture these consistently then it's better to define a method.

Note that you do get the other arguments but only if you ask for them:

```
def method_missing(name, *args)
  p [name, args]
end
```

Note that `obj['key']` shows up as `[:[], ['key']]`